# Extract azure policy assignment data that includes excluded scope(notScopes) data

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-policy

I need to extract the policy assignment data(i'm assuming it includes excluded scope data) into an excel workbook for the one of the management group 'A"

when I do a REST API call to policy assignment node the response JSON has notScopes:[] for all policies in effect at MG 'A'

what is the best way to extract all the policy assignment data that will include excluded scopes data at all levels namely MG,Subscription,and the resource group?  I tried the azure CLI route with a couple of commands from microsoft docs but doesn't seem to give me the data i'm looking for

any help on this?

Comment: You can get the assignment scope -"policyAssignmentScope": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/myManagementGroup", by calling this rest api for management group- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-states/list-query-results-for-management-group?tabs=HTTP

Comment: You can also call this API -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-set-definitions/get-at-management-group?tabs=HTTP#retrieve-a-policy-set-definition-at-management-group-level and look at Metadata > assignpermissions >assignPermissions 
boolean

Set to true to have Azure portal create role assignments on the resource ID or resource scope value of this parameter during policy assignment. This property is useful in case you wish to assign permissions outside the assignment scope.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know @SiddheshDesai Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I added an excluded scope to the Azure Built in Policy Assignment Name with SecurityCenterBuiltIn like below:-

***Go to your Policy Assignments section in Azure Policy > Select your Policy > Edit the Policy and add the Exclusion > After adding the Excluded scope Click Review + Save for excluded scope to be added successfully like below:-***

[image]

Confirm if the Excluded scope is added like below:-

[image]

> Then I called the below API from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-assignments/get?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)
>
> ```http
> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub-id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/<policy-assignment-name>?api-version=2022-06-01
> ```
>
> > 

**Output:-**

[image]

**Response with NotScope:-**

[image]

You can also call the above API via azure cli with az rest command from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest):-

```bash
az rest --method get --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub-id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/<policy-assignment-name>?api-version=2022-06-01
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

> I called this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-states/list-query-results-for-subscription?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0) in Postman to get the Policy assignment Scope at the subscription level and got the scope in the response like below:-

[image]

You call the above API via azure cli rest command like below:-

```bash
az rest --method post --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/queryResults?api-version=2019-10-01
```

**Output:-**

[image]

> To call above API at management group level refer this [MS
> Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-states/list-query-results-for-management-group?tabs=HTTP)

> Alternatively, You can call PolicyDefinitions by calling this [API1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-definitions/get?tabs=HTTP) for Subscription level and this [API-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-definitions/get-at-management-group?tabs=HTTP) for management group level and look at the assignPermissions property

Comment: I need the response with NotScope data for all the subscriptions under a given management group so I think I need to use a script in az cli to recursively  extract the NotScope parameter data for each subscription under the management group.Thank you for your suggestions.